# File location of custom Kohana ORM image upload error messages

Tags: validation, orm, kohana

I have a form that allows file uploads and I want to customize the ORM Validation error below and I don't know how.

```
models/_external.logo.Upload::image
```

Where do I place the error messages?

Comment: Search for Exeption, Kohana Message, Validation Error or write a little bit more about your Form, your Class, the Error and your file structure.. Yesterday I've worked with that :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your messages array in the file: `./application/messages/models/_external.php`

The format of the array will be:

```php
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

return array(
    'logo' => array(
        'Upload::image' => 'Invalid image!'
    )
);
```